# Adding Feature for 15% Discount on First 3 Trips in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, usermetadata

How to modify my existing code to achieve the following:

Apply a 15% discount only for the first 3 instances of a specific product (ID: 848) for each logged-in user.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_discount_for_logged_in_users', 10, 1);

function custom_discount_for_logged_in_users($cart) {
    $target_product_id = 848;
    
    if (is_user_logged_in() && in_array($target_product_id, array_column($cart->get_cart(), 'product_id'))) {
        $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.15;
        $cart->add_fee('15% Discount', -$discount, true);
    }
}
```